# PhotoPicker sample app, MyViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I recently downloaded the PhotoPicker sample code app from developer.apple.com as I am relatively new to iOS.

Why is there no initialization for `MyViewController` anywhere in the other code or in the Interface Builder nibs(that I can locate, anyway).

How does it know to run the MyViewController code files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is what I did to figure it out.

Inside the Interface Builder, the window that shows the "File's Owner" and "First Responder".
I changed the "View Mode" to show all the nesting (the last symbol of the 3).  Then I saw that MyViewController has been nested inside the Navigation Controller.  Through Interface Builder.

Thanks to everyone who gave answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check `MainWindow.xib` file, `MyViewController` has to be there, as root veiew controller of `navigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding there does not have to be a view controller. There should be a delegate at least, and a view. there are other resources as well.

There are cases where developers can break convention and use shorthand for the code and pointers.

It looks as if in the .h and .m files hand off to OverlayViewController.h/.m